# Whats wrong with my code? - dice rolling

Tags: javascript, dice

I am trying to log to the console a message saying : Gratz! You gained 5 points!' after you rolled two the same numbers after each other.

can someone explain me what is wrong with my code?

```
<script>


 var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;

  var diceRolls = [];


function rollDice() {
           var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
           var status = document.getElementById("status");               
           var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
           console.log("You rolled "+d1+".");
           diceRolls.push(d1);


  }
    if(diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 1] === d1) {
      console.log("You won 5 points!");
  }     
  </script>
```

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: @EisaAdil Is that a joke? (I hope so :P)

Comment: @Eisa Adil - your advice is not valid for pure (or almost pure) algorithems, like what he tries here

Comment: @EisaAdil: This is not something worth downloading a not-exactly-tiny JS library for.  I mean, right now, the DOM elements aren't even being used, so.  :P

Comment: @EisaAdil Please tell me that you actually know jQuery *is* Javascript... and a very large "convenience" library for it at that. A simple number calculation does **not** need jQuery, period.

Comment: I suggest you attempt to solve your problems before posting here, Youssef. Getting other people to write your code for you isn't going to help you in the long run.

Comment: Using javascript if you like reinventing the wheel over and over again. @newfurniturey That's your opinion.

Comment: @EisaAdil Throwing around phrases like that without even knowing what they mean isn't exactly helping your case

Comment: @Doorknob Then what is?

Comment: @EisaAdil: jQuery does not provide any functionality that'd be useful for this code yet.  Once he's doing any significant amount of DOM manipulation, only *then* do you get to mention jQuery without being ridiculed.

Comment: @EisaAdil Nothing, because your point is irrelevant. There is absolutely ***no*** reason to use jQuery in this case, and no reasonable JavaScript developer would do so.

Comment: @EisaAdil, tell that to jQuery

Comment: I could not help to remember this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif - LOL

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn lol. The funniest part is how the guy which states the '+ operator' is downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you're checking outside the function, and the condition is not correct. First you need to make sure that the dice has been rolled at least two times, then you compare the two last values. And as @Bergi noted, you also need to call the function, although I guess you're already doing that. Below is the correct solution:

```
var diceRolls = [];
var totalDiceRolls = 0;
// you set this to whatever you want the limit to be
var maxDiceRolls = 10;

function rollDice() {
       if (++totalDiceRolls > maxDiceRolls)
       {
           alert(maxDiceRolls + " dice rolls allowed at max!");
           return;
       }
       var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
       var status = document.getElementById("status");               
       var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
       console.log("You rolled "+d1+".");
       diceRolls.push(d1);



       if(diceRolls.length > 1 && diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 2] == d1) {
           console.log("You won 5 points!");
       } 
}
```

Comment: Also it should be noted that you need to actually call the function somewhere then :-)

Comment: can you please explain me in easy language what this line means? : if(diceRolls.length > 1 && diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 2] == d1) {

Comment: For reference, the length check isn't strictly necessary here.  `d1` will never be undefined, but `diceRolls['-1']` will be unless you're doing something very odd...so in normal use, the first roll will always be unequal to the as-yet-nonexistent previous roll.

Comment: @Youssef , diceRolls.length > 1 means that there are at least 2 elements in diceRolls, which means the dice has been rolled at least twice. diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 2] gets the second to last element, and we compare that to d1, which is the current dice. If both those conditions are true, then we have a winner :)

Comment: but I use a button to roll the dice, so is the length check necessary?

Comment: As @cHao noted, it's not necessary to check it, so I removed it.

Comment: @Youssef: It's not necessary...but it does let people know that your code isn't *accidentally* working.  :)  IE: that you thought about the case when you don't have two rolls yet.  I wouldn't include it, but some people would recommend it.

Comment: @cHao I'd removed it, but I loved the part "isn't accidentally working.", so I decided to include it again.

Comment: but guys, isnt it impossible to ever get The message that you won after to the same numbers, if you dont hit the button 2 times yet? isnt it a bit logical? :p

Comment: @Youssef I don't get your point. You only get the message if you get two consecutive same dices.

Comment: Well, you said you should be sure if the dice has been rolled at least twice. But isnt dat logical if you award points for two sequential identical rolls?

Comment: @Youssef: The first time your function is called, we assume you haven't rolled any dice before.  That is, `diceRolls.length == 0`, and after appending `d1`, it'll be 1.  So without the check that the length is at least 2, `diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 2]` will have you checking element -1 of the array.  It's basically personal preference whether you explicitly check or assume the value is undefined (which it will be, unless you've set it at some point).

Comment: Thank you guys! One last point: how do i save set a maximum for the array pushes? Like you only only throw 10 times at max.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me out with a pointssystem that starts at 10, and then per throw downcounts, and reminds how many points youve eventually earned and got left?

Comment: @Youssef sorry but no. You should make it yourself. I believe it is out of the scope of this question. I've already helped you enough. Now please, if the answer has been helpful, mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You never loop the result, and you assign d1 with a random number, but do nothing with it.

You need to roll the dice and each time, loop the array to find if 2 numbers are the same, at the moment you don't loop, so there is no way to know if 2 numbers are equals.

Comment: There's no need to loop. You only need the two last elements of the array.

Comment: Looping through the array isn't necessary, and in fact would give the wrong result if the intent is to only award points for two *sequential* identical rolls.  (And if it were to award points for rolling something that was already rolled *ever*, a plain object --or an array with 6 elements -- would be better for tracking that.)